# Cannot clone github repository

Tags: git, github

Based on this guide:
https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape

I am running a script on Ubuntu that clones a set of github repositories:
https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape/blob/develop/cy.sh

It fails with:

```
$ ./cy.sh init
Target directory = 
Cytoscape project will be cloned to: /home/user/projects/cytoscape
Cloning: parent (URI = git@github.com:cytoscape/cytoscape-parent.git)
Cloning into 'parent'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Could not clone remote repository: /home/user/projects/cytoscape
```

If I instead from command line do:

```
git clone https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape-parent.git
```

it works.

on what systems does:

```
git clone git@github.com:cytoscape/cytoscape-parent.git
```

work?

Comment: You need an SSH key to use the SSH URL. See https://help.github.com/articles/generating-an-ssh-key/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`git clone git@github.com:cytoscape/cytoscape-parent.git`command means you want to clone using SSH URLs . SSH URLs provide access to a Git repository via SSH which is a secure protocol. To use these URLs, you must generate an SSH keypair on your computer and add the public key to your GitHub account.  Go through this for setting up an SSH keypair. [Generating an SSH key](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-an-ssh-key/)

Answer (score 2):

The script defaults to cloning an SSH url. Setting up the SSH keys has been linked to in another answer. Your other alternative is:

1. Change the script to clone HTTP URLs which don't require this setup. In your particular case you should be cloning https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape-parent.git
2. Send a patch to the project to change the default, making cloning easier for casual users.